# can I register the same app twice under two different names in Django?

Tags: django

I know that sounds a bit weird task, but if I have one app, called `App1` in my project folder, can I add it twice under two different names (let say `App1_1`, and `App1_2`? I know that it is theoretically possible using `AppConfig` but when I try to do it the error `Application names aren't unique, duplicates: foo” is raised.

Comment: So then give them different names?

Comment: Have you tried copying the app and renaming it? That could be a work-around to using the same app.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: nope, when I try to change the name parameter in AppConfig, then it returns the error 'such a module is not found'

Comment: So then specify the path?

Comment: I was probably unclear: I mean the goal is to put the same app under two different names in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

Comment: Instead of saying this is a weird task, you should probably say why you want to acheive this, because at a glance this is probably a bad practice that could be easily fixed by something else.

Comment: yes, I basically need the same application with two different configurations

Comment: What do you mean by _configurations_ ?